# Are there any problems installing Office 2016 over Office 2013 directly?

Tags: installation, best-practices, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office-2016

Are there any problems if I install Office 2016 over Office 2013 without uninstalling Office 2013 first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether or not the issues listed by Microsoft affect you. If they do, then they're problems.

https://community.office365.com/en-us/w/officeapps/office-2016-problems-and-solutions-and-frequently-asked-questions

- Outlook 2016 requires features that are not available in Exchange 2007
- Office 365 Business subscribers using OneNote 2016 may be unable to edit, save, or sync OneNote Notebooks stored on SharePoint or OneDrive for Business. Some users may see the following error message:  "To continue using this notebook, activate with an eligible Office 365 subscription"
- OneDrive for Business is uninstalled after you upgrade to Office 2016
- OneDrive for Business stops syncing libraries, or the icon overlays don't appear on synchronized files and folders after you install Office 2016
- If there is a 2013 version of Visio Pro for Office 365 or Project Pro for Office 365 installed on the computer when you manually update Office to the Office 2016 version, those versions of Visio and Project are removed from the computer. You won’t be able to reinstall them after the Office installation finishes.

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/09/22/office-2016-install-caveats.aspx

- Quite a lot of new and upcoming features in Office 2016 have a focus on enabling collaboration. However, many of those new features depend on having an Office 365 subscription in place and aren't available in the standalone boxed product.

http://www.groovypost.com/unplugged/observations-installing-office-2016-pro-plus/

- It does side-by-side installs with older versions. My older version of Office 2013 was left intact after installing Office 2016. What happens when you try to open an Office file? It defaults to the 2016 version. This also means you’ll need to manually uninstall the older version if you don’t want it.